# Find the limit of $e^x/2^x$ as $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: limits

I am trying to find the asymptotic relation between $e^x$ and $2^x$. I tried to use limit comparison: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^x}{2^x}\right)$$

I tried to use L'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^x}{2^x}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^x}{\ln(2) \cdot 2^x}\right)$$

which doesn't really help. Is there any way to compute this limit? Thanks!

Comment: Try using $a^x=e^{x\ln(a)}$

Comment: $\frac{e}{2}\gt 1$

Comment: Your L'Hospital's rule approach actually works. Say the limit is $L$. You showed $L=\frac1{\ln2}L$, so the limit, if it exists, is zero. But it obviously isn't zero, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\cfrac{e^x}{2^x}\right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\cfrac{e}{2}\right)^x = \infty \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

because $e > 2$ so $\frac{e}{2} > 1$.

Comment: Yeah, it can't get any simpler than this approach.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

$$\frac{e^x}{2^x}=\frac{e^x}{e^{x\ln2}}=e^{x(1-\ln 2)}$$

Then:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{x(1-\ln 2)}= ?$$